# how to get started with doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

where can i find help getting started with doctrine? forums etc?

I'm trying to follow this;

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/getting-started/pl

but it refers to a Doctrine.php file that's located in the lib folder. There is no lib folder in the doctrine download. There is a bin folder with a doctrine file in itIs that what they are refering to?

What should the folder structure look like for a doctrine project? Currently i have this;

```
application
library
   |
   |-----Doctrine
           |
           |------common
           |------DBAL
           |------ORM
```

Where should the Doctine.php file go?

Comment: Your link goes to old, 1.2 version of Doctrine. Are you shure to study outdated version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine uses PEARlike naming conventions, so Doctrine.php goes into the root of your include_path, or to the root of your library, next to the Doctrine directory. However, newer versions of Doctrine1 only keep this file for backwards compatibility. You should rather use 'Doctrine_Core' it 's the same class, but with a new name (and location).

Comment: You can also try this tutorial: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/introduction.html